# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.without_sticking not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

we have a rails application which we have upgraded from rails 4 to rails 5 (5.0.7.2)
and see that `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.without_sticking` is no longer working.

and we see the error which I think might be related to `makara` gem

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `without_sticking' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x00007f7c92b9fa80>):
```

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.without_sticking do
        find_by_sql(sql)
 end
```

Any help on how to fix would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: "No longer working" is unfortunately too vague for us to be able to assist. Can you please elaborate? The only reference to `without_sticking` that I can find appears to belong to the [`makara`](https://github.com/instacart/makara) gem so maybe there is some assistance there as well

Comment: hi @engineersmnky sorry for a late reply on this. Yes, I am using the `makara` gem, however, after the rails upgrade I see the error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'without_sticking' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x00007f7c92b9fa80>):`

Comment: it seems like the ActiveRecord::Base.connection object is not an instance of the MakaraMysql2Adapter but rather a regular Mysql2Adapter. To fix this issue, you need to ensure that your database.yml is configured to use the Makara adapter. After updating your config/database.yml with the Makara adapter, restart your Rails application and try using without_sticking again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it used to work in *rails 4*, but here is how it works in *rails 5*:

```bash
rbenv shell 2.7.6 
gem install rails --version 5.0.7.2
rails _5.0.7.2_ new rails_five_zero -d mysql  
cd rails_five_zero
rbenv local 2.7.6
bundle add makara   # v0.5.0
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "rails_five_zero_development"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

DB configuration has been like this since [v0.2.0.beta3](https://github.com/instacart/makara/tree/v0.2.0.beta3#databaseyml), 2013:

```yaml
# config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypassword
  host: 127.0.0.1

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_five_zero_development

  # NOTE: make sure to specify makara adapter
  #       if you put it here, it will only be available in development
  adapter: 'mysql2_makara'
  makara:
    connections:
      - role: master
        host: 127.0.0.1
# ...
```

*https://github.com/instacart/makara/tree/v0.5.0#databaseyml*

```bash
docker compose up -d
bin/rails c
```

```rb
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
=> "Mysql2"

>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
=> ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MakaraMysql2Adapter
# NOTE: this has to be makara adapter^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.method :without_sticking
=> #<Method: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MakaraMysql2Adapter(Makara::Proxy)#without_sticking() /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/makara-0.5.0/lib/makara/proxy.rb:74>

?> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.without_sticking do
?>   "don't know what to do here"
>> end
=> "don't know what to do here"
```

---

If you don't have `makara:` config it doesn't work:

```bash
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:create
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails c
```

```rb
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
=> ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
#                                    ^

>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.without_sticking
NoMethodError (undefined method `without_sticking' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x000055a3fbdf76a0>)
```